# RxSwift : Observe each element observable property in observable array

Tags: arrays, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have a list of player which I want each player stamina to be observed and the observer should be the same. (Sharing observer maybe)

```
class Player {
  var stamina = Variable(10)
}

let player1 = Player()
let player2 = Player()

var playerList = Variable([player1, player2])
```

So, whenever player1.stamina == 0 then I can delete player1 from the list, dan now only player2 to be observed.

Comment: Variable is deprecated as of RxSwift v4.0

Comment: Interesting. I just know about that. So what to use after Variable deprecated? Thanks for your information.

Comment: Current recommended replacement for this API is `RxCocoa.BehaviorRelay`

Comment: Could you please share me a link? I need to read more about this change. Thanks. @iWheelBuy

Comment: @muizmoses https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Deprecated.swift

Comment: "Deprecates Variable in favor of BehaviorRelay"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use Observable.combineLatest to combine all latest event in array's element's property

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
class Player {
    let stamina = Variable(0)
}

// ViewController
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

// Array
let playerList: Variable<[Player]> = Variable([])

// Observing each player stamina at once
playerList.asObservable()
.flatMapLatest { players -> Observable<[Int]> in 
    let playerStaminaObservableList = players.map { $0.stamina.asObservable() }
    return Observable.combineLatest { playerStaminaObservableList }
}
.subscribe(onNext: {
    print("List of playerStamina: \($0)")
})
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Feel free to correct any mistake.